# Cannot connect via SSH from Github Action workflow

Tags: ssh, digital-ocean, github-actions, ssh-keygen, droplet

Connection to created Droplet via SSH by Github Actions runner.

My steps:

1. `ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/KEY_NAME -P ""`
2. `doctl compute ssh-key create KEY --public-key "CONTENT OF KEY_NAME.pub"`
3. `doctl compute droplet create --image ubuntu-20-04-x64 --size s-1vcpu-1gb --region fra1 DROPLET_NAME --ssh-keys FINGERPRINT --wait`
4. `ssh -vvv -i ~/.ssh/KEY_NAME root@DROPLET_IP`

✔️ Tested on Windows local machine using `doctl.exe` runned from `cmd` - works!
✔️ Tested on Docker (installed on Windows) based on Linux image using `doctl` script - works!
⚠️ Tested on Github Actions runner based on ubuntu-latest using `digitalocean/action-doctl` script - doesn't work!

Received message is: `connect to host ADDRESS_IP port 22: Connection refused`.

So the steps are correct, so why does this not work for Github Actions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the GitHub Action [digitalocean/action-doctl](https://github.com/digitalocean/action-doctl), check [issue 14](https://github.com/digitalocean/action-doctl/issues/14#issuecomment-563496515) first:

> In order to SSH into a Droplet, doctl needs access to the private half of the SSH key pair whose public half is on the Droplet.
> Currently the doctl Action is based on a Docker container.
>
> If you were using the Docker container directly, you could invoke it with:
>
> ```sh
> docker run --rm --interactive --tty \
>  --env=DIGITALOCEAN_ACCESS_TOKEN=<YOUR-DO-API-TOKEN> \
>  -v $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa:/root/.ssh/id_rsa \
>  digitalocean/doctl compute ssh <DROPLET-ID>
> ```
>
> in order to mount the SSH key from outside the container.
>
> You might be better off just using `doctl` to grep the Droplet's IP address and using this Action that is more focused on SSH related use cases and provides a lot of additional functionality: [`marketplace/actions/ssh-remote-commands`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/ssh-remote-commands).